Can we put if else condition on runs-on: for the choice of workflow runner?
Below job Deployment runs the strategy matrix while job name set-environment-matrix constructs the strategy matrix variable ENV-MATRIX.
My requirement is to choose a different runner group called Dot-Shared or runs-on: "Windows-latest" if the job name contains Approvers else it should runs-on: "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
  set-environment-matrix:
    name: Set Environment Matrix for ${{ inputs.customWorkflow }}
    needs: set-global-runner  
    runs-on: "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
    outputs:
      env-matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.ENV-MATRIX }}
    steps:
      - name: prereq
        id: set-matrix
        run: |
          ...
          ...

          $envList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
          foreach($envName in $QueryResult.EnvironmentName){

            $skipApproval = $QueryResult | Where-Object { $_.EnvironmentName -eq $envName } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty skipApproval
            Write-Host "skipApproval value for $envName is $skipApproval"
            
          $srepo="$sreponame/environments/$envName"
          $envuri ="$apiUrl"+"$srepo"
          try {
          $respEnv = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $envuri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/vnd.github+json" -UseBasicParsing
          echo "respEnv: $respEnv"
          $sEnvs=$respEnv.Content | convertfrom-json
             } catch {
              Write-host "$envName not found"
              exit 1
             }
             $envList.Add($envName)
          }
          $EnvNamesJSONVariable.Add("ENVNAME",$envList) 
          echo "ENV-MATRIX=$($EnvNamesJSONVariable | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress -Depth 100)" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  Deployment:
    name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
    needs: [set-environment-matrix, set-global-runner]
    environment: 
      name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
      url: "${{ steps.prereq.outputs.appurl }}"
    #runs-on: "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
    runs-on: 
      if: contains(matrix.envName, 'Approvers')
      value: Dot-Shared
      else: ${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}    
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.set-environment-matrix.outputs.ENV-MATRIX)}}

    steps:

      - name: Track & Record Approvers List
        run: |
          ...
          ...

Can you please suggest?
*********** UPDATE ************
post suggestion from user @GuiFalourd i tried the below but it did not help and no jobs are populated in the matrix
          $runnerList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
          $envObjects = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
          foreach($envName in $QueryResult.EnvironmentName){
          
            $runnerToAdd = $null
              if ($envName -like "*approvers*") {
                $runnerToAdd = "windows-latest"
              } else {
                $runnerToAdd = "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
              }
              $runnerList.Add($runnerToAdd)
               

              $envObject = @{
                "ENVNAME" = $envName
                "RUNNERNAME" = $runnerName
              }

              $envObjects.Add($envObject)
             
           }

          $EnvNamesJSONVariable = @{
            "ENVOBJECTS" = $envObjects
          }
        
          echo "ENV-MATRIX=$($EnvNamesJSONVariable | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress -Depth 100)" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"


  Deployment:
    name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
    needs: [set-environment-matrix, set-global-runner]
    environment: 
      name: ${{ matrix.envObjects.envName }}
      url: "${{ steps.prereq.outputs.appurl }}"
    #runs-on: "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
    runs-on: "${{ matrix.envObjects.runnerName }}"

    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.set-environment-matrix.outputs.ENV-MATRIX)}}
      #matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.set-environment-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX)}}

    steps:
      ...
      ...

Kindly suggest.

You can't use the jobs.jobId.run field with conditions like that. However, you could already save the expected runner in the set-environment-matrix job, and add this value in the output, using objects. You would have a list of matrix.EnvObject in the first job output, that would contains a matrix.EnvObject.EnvName and matrix.EnvObject.EnvRunner to use in the Deployment job configurations.

@GuiFalourd i tried your suggestion and updated the details in original post. Could you please have and look and suggest how can i get the matrix jobs to showup. Currently, its blank.

@GuiFalourd can u please suggest as i m not able to construct the desire list for the matrix in the updated post.

I created an example here to help you with the configuration. The output can be found here. You just have to guarantee the output from the first job will generate the list you expect to manipulate in your matrix strategy in the second job.

Did you make it work?

Yes @GuiFalourd... I will update this post later today

You can't use the jobs.jobId.run field with conditions like that.
However, an option could be to already save the expected runner in the set-environment-matrix job, and add this value in the output, using objects in the matrix strategy.
That way, you would have a list of matrix.object in the first job output, that would contains a matrix.object.envName and matrix.object.envRunner to use in the Deployment job configurations.
Here is an example of how to use the matrix in that case:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.object.envRunner }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        object: [{"envName":"dev", "envRunner":"ubuntu-latest"}, {"envName":"stg", "envRunner":"windows-latest"}, {"envName":"prd", "envRunner":"macos-latest"}]
      fail-fast: true
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo ${{ matrix.object.envName }}

In your case, you'll have to guarantee the output from the first job will generate the JSON list you expect to manipulate in your matrix strategy in the second job.
Note: The workflow run associated to this configuration (workflow file) can be found here
